# Can we create database in postgresql using fluent migrator in C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, fluent, fluent-migrator

My requirement is to create new database when user create new company from admin panel. I am using asp.net mvc and fluent migrator for table creation. However, initially I need to create the database based on the input given by the admin the "Add New Company" form. The database to be created will be in postgresql v9.5

Answer (score 0):

I have got similar requirements in past, I had done some research but for creating new database I was not successful with fluentmigrator.
For creating tables and index with fluentmigrator worked awesome. 
So, I decided to create it using c# without fluentmigrator like below

I have used NpgSQL nuget package, I have created below function to check whether database exists. if that doesn't exist then need to create new

for creating and checking database exists or not, you need to connect to "postgres" database with NpgsqlConnection object

```
public static bool DBExists(string connectionStr, string dbname)
    {
        using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionStr))
        {
            string sql = $"SELECT DATNAME FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE DATNAME = '{dbname}'";
            using (NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand
                (sql, conn))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    var i = command.ExecuteScalar();
                    conn.Close();
                    if (i != null && i.ToString().Equals(dbname)) //always 'true' (if it exists) or 'null' (if it doesn't)
                        return true;
                    else return false;
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For creating database you can ExecuteNonQuery on NpgsqlCommand with NpgsqlConnection object connected to postgres database.

```
string sql = "CREATE DATABASE \"dbname\" WITH OWNER = postgres ENCODING = 'UTF8' CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;";
```

for my requirements, I also needed to create an extension, which I was able to create using below query

```
string sql = "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext WITH SCHEMA public;";
```

I hope this will help.